# Is it correct and good Java style to use an abstract class in this example?

Tags: java, heap

I am implementing an integer heap data structure in Java. However, there are two kinds of heaps I want to implement: a min heap and a max heap. I was thinking of doing the following:

```
abstract class Heap {

      private int data[]; //the heap implemented using an array
      private int size; //how large of a heap
      private int numberOfElements; //how many items currently in the heap

      public Heap( int size ) {

            this.size = size;
            this.data = new int[ size + 1 ];
            this.numberOfElements = 0;
      }

      public abstract void insert( int data );

      public abstract void delete( int data );

}
```

And then I was going to make two derived classes

```
class MinHeap extends Heap {

      //call super() and use the three data fields above
      //of course here I will add the abstract methods insert and delete
      //and code them according to the min heap specifications
}

 class MaxHeap extends Heap {

      //call super() and use the three data fields above
      //of course here I will add the abstract methods insert and delete
      //and code them according to the maxheap specifications

}
```

Would this be considered good, okay, neutral or bad style? I am relatively new to the basic object oriented design techniques. I was first thinking to make Heap an interface, but since no matter what kind of heap I create, I want there to always be a data array, a size and a `numberOfElements` variable, so I thought this may be best implemented as an abstract class. I want to create re-usable generic code. Also, I know in this case instead of using an `int` array, I could make a `Comparable` array instead.

Comment: It's the matter of taste I'd say... I think that you can implement it also in such way, that comparator is a parameter (while you have just `int`s in heap, that can be true/false parameter).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to change the access modifier of your fields in your base class to `protected` (or like [Jamey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1393963/jamey) in the comment below suggested) add getters and setter. Apart from that you've done it the right way.

Comment: Or add getters/setters.

Comment: @Jamey Correct, thanks for pointing that out. I edited the answer, giving credits to you